# Maven updatePolicy vs -U

Tags: maven, maven-3

In Settings file of maven 3, we can specify

```
<updatePolicy></updatePolicy>
```

for each of the repo. 
This will control how often maven will look this repo for updated version of snapshots.

Also, we can use

```
mvn   -U
```

to force maven to look of updated version of Snapshot.

My guess is both are doing the same thing.

I'm curious to know which one of this will take precedent.
Which method to use if I want to check updated versions of snapshot always.

Which one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty much you're right, they're doing the same thing.

However, there is a difference. For `<updatePolicy>` it's possible to specify how often to re-check the snapshots. The value can be `always` (check always), `interval:X` (check every `X` minutes) `daily` (check every day) and `never` (ignores any checks).

`-U` argument works the same as specifying `always` for the `<updatePolicy>`, but is valid only for that one single command it's executed with. So generally it's good to use when you know that a colleague fixed something which you want to get immediately.

Comment: Also, I found out that -U just check the checksum with remote repo, if not matched with local repo, maven will download the jar . But, In case of <updatePolicy> maven will always download the jar from remote repo